# React-Native Flatlist's onViewableItemChanged error

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to account for changes when the element in view changes.
I get the following

`Invariant Violation: Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported`

I have the following

```
<Animated.FlatList
      viewabilityConfig={carouselViewabilityConfig}
      onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
      ...//other properties
/>
```

and my functions are

```
  const onViewableItemsChanged = ({
    viewableItems,
  }: {
    viewableItems: Array<number>;
  }) => {
    const insightsById = savedInsights.byId;
    console.log('byId:!', insightsById);
    if (!viewableItems.length) {
      return;
    }

    const visibleInsightId =
      insightsById[viewableItems[Math.max(viewableItems.length - 2, 0)].index];
    console.log(visibleInsightId);
    Analytics.logViewItem({ insight_id: visibleInsightId });
    // const visibleInsightIndex = insightsById.indexOf(visibleInsightId);
  };

  const carouselViewabilityConfig = {
    waitForInteraction: false,
    minimumViewTime: 100,
    viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50,
  };
```

I saw a method using `refs` but it didn't work, my function wouldn't run.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem in recent versions! I don't know why :((

Comment: I'm working on finding a fix. Will let you know if I find anything.